# Create (draw) barcode image from array in google doc using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to generate and paste barcode image in a google doc. I've found out how to create a js array, which represents it, using google script. But have no idea how to create and paste an image from this array into google doc. Although it's easy to create an SVG image in a simple web page.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you want to initially start by opening the doc, and working from there?  Do you need to see the doc afterwards?  You can create a sidebar in a Doc created with HTML.  Do you want to start from a web page? What's an acceptable starting point?

Comment: If you have code that you are using, maybe edit your question, and add it.  Like the code to generate the bar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get something like a jQuery pluggin to work with the new iFrame HTML service, then you could create the bar code in HTML, then save the image to an image file.  Then get the file as a blob.

If the new iFrame HTML Service will accept a pluggin, and allow a Canvas tag, it could work that way.

I don't know of a way to code your own JavaScript to make the bar code.  I think you'd want to start with seeing what is available out there on the internet.

You are asking a very broad question, that would require something like a tutorial to provide an answer.

Code to insert image from Original Poster:

```
function insertImage() {
  var baseUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl);

  doc.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob());
};
```

Original Generic function:

```
function insertImage() {

  var Doc = DocumentApp.openById('Your Doc ID here');
  var image = DocsList.getFileById('Your Image ID here');

  // Use this if the Doc is open and code running is bound to this doc
  //var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var body = Doc.getBody();
  var whatParagraph = 3; //Insert an image in the fourth paragraph

  body.insertImage(image);// 'image' is the image file as blob
  //body.appendImage(whatParagraph, image); // Either insert or append can be used
}
```

Comment: Sandy Good, thanks for your answer. 
For now the problem is that i don`t know how to save an image from canvas to google drive. It would make everything much easier.

I have js plugin, which generates an array of 0 and 1. Than canvas item can be created on HTML page using this array. But how to import this canvas into the doc file?

Comment: Base64 encoding helped me:) var baseUrl=canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl); doc.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob()); Maybe there is more effective way to paste the canvas item into the doc file.. I don`t know

Comment: Yes, the first function now works. The second one i didn`t check

Answer (score 0):

You have accepted answer, but as an alternative I'd be tempted to hand off the barcode generation to a published API. There are a few.

e.g. http://www.scandit.com/2012/12/11/create-your-own-barcodes-with-scandits-new-barcode-generator/

Reason being that liability caveats aside, there is a maintained  implementation test by results. Not to judge your ability, just thinking of good practice.